# How to convert string labels to one-hot vectors in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and would like to read a comma separated values (csv) file, containing 2 columns, column 1 the index, and column 2 a label string. I have the following code which reads lines in the csv file line by line and I am able to get the data in the csv file correctly using print statements. However, I would like to do one-hot encoding conversion from the string labels and do not how to do it in TensorFlow. The final goal is to use the tf.train.batch() function so I can get batches of one-hot label vectors to train a neural network.

As you can see in the code below, I can create a one-hot vector for each of the label entries manually within a TensorFlow session. But how do I use the tf.train.batch() function? If I move the line

```
label_batch = tf.train.batch([col2], batch_size=5)
```

into the TensorFlow session block (replacing col2 with label_one_hot), the program blocks doing nothing. I tried to move the one-hot vector conversion outside the TensorFlow session but I failed to get it to work correctly. What is the correct way to do it? Please help.

```
label_files = []
label_files.append(LABEL_FILE)
print "label_files: ", label_files

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(label_files)

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
print "key:", key, ", value:", value

record_defaults = [['default_id'], ['default_label']]
col1, col2 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(LABEL_FILE))

label_batch = tf.train.batch([col2], batch_size=5)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coordinator)

    for i in range(100):
        column1, column2 = sess.run([col1, col2])

        index = 0
        if column2 == 'airplane':
            index = 0
        elif column2 == 'automobile':
            index = 1
        elif column2 == 'bird':
            index = 2
        elif column2 == 'cat':
            index = 3
        elif column2 == 'deer':
            index = 4
        elif column2 == 'dog':
            index = 5
        elif column2 == 'frog':
            index = 6
        elif column2 == 'horse':
            index = 7
        elif column2 == 'ship':
            index = 8
        elif column2 == 'truck':
            index = 9

        label_one_hot = tf.one_hot([index], 10)  # depth=10 for 10 categories
        print "column1:", column1, ", column2:", column2
        # print "onehot label:", sess.run([label_one_hot])

    print sess.run(label_batch)

    coordinator.request_stop()
    coordinator.join(threads)
```

Comment: Do you want someone to fix all your code, or to show you how to use one-hot encoder in TF?

Comment: I believe I know how to use TF's one-hot encoder, as shown in the code above. Maybe I should say how do I convert from string label to a one-hot vector using TF's computational graph. Thank you.

Comment: Basically what I want is when col2 is equal to one of the 10 label strings, get the label index, then change value of col2 to a one-hot vector. Do this for all the entries, then after that return the whole batch of one-hot labels.

Answer (score 4):

It's been more than 2 years since this question was asked, but this answer might still be relevant for some. Here's one simple way to transform string labels into one-hot vectors in TF:

```
import tensorflow as tf

vocab = ['a', 'b', 'c']

input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=(None,))
matches = tf.stack([tf.equal(input, s) for s in vocab], axis=-1)
onehot = tf.cast(matches, tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(onehot, feed_dict={input: ['c', 'a']})
    print(out) # prints [[0. 0. 1.]
               #         [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try to feed your `index` variable into a placeholder, which, in turn gets transformed into a one-hot vector via `tf.one_hot`? Something along these lines:

```
lbl = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, [YOUR_BATCH_SIZE])
lbl_one_hot = tf.one_hot(lbl, YOUR_VOCAB_SIZE, 1.0, 0.0)
lb_h = sess.run([lbl_one_hot], feed_dict={lbl: index})
```

Not sure if you are doing things in batches, so if not in your case YOUR_BATCH_SIZE might be irrelevant. You can also do it using numpy.zeros, but I find the above cleaner and easier, especially with batching.

Comment: With this method, we prepare the label index list outside TF? How do I do everything inside TF?

Comment: You mean how to map the string labels to integers inside TF? If so I'm afraid I haven't come across that one. Hopefully someone else will answer. I'd imagine it's much easier to do it outside, such as with PD DataFrame

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Maybe I should do it outside too. Thanks @VS_FF!

Comment: @so_user You can use `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899462/convert-tf-string-character-array-to-vector-of-1-hot-encoded-float32-arrays) for details.

Comment: @so_user in my answer, everything happens within the computational graph