# Convert tf.string character array to vector of 1-hot-encoded float32 arrays?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing a feature engineering method for my TensorFlow model. I am trying to convert a `tf.string` to a vector of 1-hot encodings based on the characters in it.

Specifically, lets say I have a TF input string of "UDRLURDL" (In my case, each character corresponds to a direction.). I want to convert that string to a vector of say 1-hot encoded float32s. We have 4 characters (UDRL), so the 1-hot encoded output would be

```
[
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
]
```

I more or less didn't see any TF ops that operated on individual characters within a string. Can we somehow treat a `tf.string` as a character array and do this conversion?

## My final solution (inspired by @hars):

```
  original_string = tf.squeeze(original_string, axis=1)
  split_string = tf.string_split(original_string, delimiter="")

  table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
      mapping=tf.constant(["U", "D", "L", "R"]), num_oov_buckets=0)
  indices = table.lookup(split_string.values)
  embeddings = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 1, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]])
  encoded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, indices)
```

Comment: Use tf.string_split(s, delimiter=""), if you want to split it to characters. Look here:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split

Comment: Could you use something like embeddings just like in word2vec (tf.nn.embedding_lookup )  ??https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could convert your string from "UDRL" to "3210". 
You could do this using tf.nn.embeddings_lookup as shown here:

```
embeddings = tf.constant([[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]])
labels = [0,3,1,2]
encode_tensors = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings,labels)
```

Output of sess.run(encode_tensors) :

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something inspired by your answer. See my edit. Basically, I first convert the string to a vector of numbers via a lookup table before using an embedding.

Comment: nice to see your final implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer use one hot instead of embedding_lookup.

```
import tensorflow as tf

vocabulary = "UDLR"
original_string = "UDLRUDLR"
mapping_characters = tf.string_split([vocabulary], delimiter="")
input_characters = tf.string_split([original_string], delimiter="")
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
    mapping=mapping_characters.values, default_value=0)
encoded = tf.one_hot(table.lookup(input_characters.values), 
                     len(vocabulary), dtype=tf.int8)
tf.InteractiveSession().as_default()
tf.tables_initializer().run()
print(encoded.eval())
```

result:

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```